# Why error in cross compiling Arm Linux GCC?

Tags: gcc, arm, cross-compiling, embedded-linux, toolchain

I'm trying to use AppWeb, and i wrote a very simple program to embed AppWeb into my application, it's using a function in AppWeb library.

```
#include <appweb/appweb.h>
int main(int argc, char** argv)
{
    return maRunWebServer("appweb.conf");
}
```

I dont know when I compile with gcc (or cc), it compiled successful. But, when I cross compile to Arm architecture, is have been getting error.
This is my Makefile:

```
CC = gcc

LIBS = lib

FLAG = -lappweb -lmpr

TEST_TARGET = embed-appweb
OBJS = embed-appweb

all: clean compile

compile: run
    $(CC) -Wall -L$(LIBS) $(FLAG) -o $(TEST_TARGET) $(OBJS).o

run:
    $(CC) -Wall -L$(LIBS) $(FLAG) -c $(OBJS).c

clean:
    @rm -rf $(TEST_TARGET) $(TEST_TARGET).trc *.o *~
    @echo "Clean complete"
```

I was replace "CC = gcc" to "CC = arm-linux-gcc" in oder to cross compile.
The error in my problem is:

```
arm-linux-gcc -Wall -Llib -lappweb -lmpr -c embed-appweb.c
embed-appweb.c:1:27: error: appweb/appweb.h: No such file or directory
embed-appweb.c: In function 'main':
embed-appweb.c:4: warning: implicit declaration of function 'maRunWebServer'
make: *** [run] Error 1
```

and i'm sure that the library "libappweb.so" was exist in my folder "lib"

Someone may tell me, why it got error? and give me some advice?

Thanks,

Comment: What errors are you getting? Are you sure you have the required libraries cross-compiled and installed at the required places?

Comment: Error in question: No error provided.

Comment: ah, im sorry about that :D I added my error into my post ^^

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Do you know how to use the **-I** option of gcc?

The error you are getting is due to the fact that the compiler (gcc) can find the files you wanted to include.

Simplest solution would be to change the FLAG in your Makefile:

```
FLAG = -lappweb -lmpr
```

to

```
FLAG = -lappweb -lmpr -I/path/to/my/headers
```

Of course you must change /path/to/my/headers to the true path where your headers reside.

Answer (score 1):

You have to install (or symbolically link) the appweb header into the arm-linux-gcc include tree.

For example, the `arm-linux-gcc` command for one of my systems is

```
$ which arm-linux-gcc
/home/eldk/usr/bin/arm-linux-gcc
```

So the include files *that* compiler uses are:

```
 $ arm-linux-gcc -print-search-dirs
install: /home/eldk/usr/lib/gcc/arm-linux-gnueabi/4.2.2/
programs: =/home/eldk/usr/bin/../libexec/gcc/arm-linux-gnueabi/4.2.2/:/home/eldk/usr/bin/../libexec/gcc/:/home/eldk/usr/lib/gcc/arm-linux-gnueabi/4.2.2/:/home/eldk/usr/lib/gcc/arm-linux-gnueabi/4.2.2/:/home/eldk/usr/lib/gcc/arm-linux-gnueabi/:/usr/libexec/gcc/arm-linux-gnueabi/4.2.2/:/usr/libexec/gcc/arm-linux-gnueabi/:/home/eldk/usr/libexec/gcc/arm-linux-gnueabi/4.2.2/:/home/eldk/usr/bin/../lib/gcc/arm-linux-gnueabi/4.2.2/../../../../arm-linux-gnueabi/bin/arm-linux-gnueabi/4.2.2/:/home/eldk/usr/bin/../lib/gcc/arm-linux-gnueabi/4.2.2/../../../../arm-linux-gnueabi/bin/:/home/eldk/usr/lib/gcc/arm-linux-gnueabi/4.2.2/../../../../arm-linux-gnueabi/bin/arm-linux-gnueabi/4.2.2/:/home/eldk/usr/lib/gcc/arm-linux-gnueabi/4.2.2/../../../../arm-linux-gnueabi/bin/
libraries: =/home/eldk/usr/bin/../lib/gcc/arm-linux-gnueabi/4.2.2/:/home/eldk/usr/bin/../lib/gcc/:/home/eldk/usr/lib/gcc/arm-linux-gnueabi/4.2.2/:/usr/libexec/gcc/arm-linux-gnueabi/4.2.2/:/home/eldk/usr/bin/../lib/gcc/arm-linux-gnueabi/4.2.2/../../../../arm-linux-gnueabi/lib/arm-linux-gnueabi/4.2.2/:/home/eldk/usr/bin/../lib/gcc/arm-linux-gnueabi/4.2.2/../../../../arm-linux-gnueabi/lib/:/home/eldk/usr/lib/gcc/arm-linux-gnueabi/4.2.2/../../../../arm-linux-gnueabi/lib/arm-linux-gnueabi/4.2.2/:/home/eldk/usr/lib/gcc/arm-linux-gnueabi/4.2.2/../../../../arm-linux-gnueabi/lib/:/home/eldk/usr/../arm/lib/arm-linux-gnueabi/4.2.2/:/home/eldk/usr/../arm/lib/:/home/eldk/usr/../arm/usr/lib/arm-linux-gnueabi/4.2.2/:/home/eldk/usr/../arm/usr/lib/
```

Comment: Your meaning is I have to copy appweb header into arm-linux-gcc include tree?

My **arm-linux-gcc**:
`# which arm-linux-gcc
/media/Learning/Embedded-Systems/Soft/gcc-4.3.2/local/arm/4.3.2/bin/arm-linux-gcc`

or how can i linking appweb header to arm-linux-gcc?

Answer (score 0):

You have two concerns:

1. Your include search path (as already pointed by sessyargc.jp and wallyk).
2. Your library search path.

When you compile using `gcc`, it will use your gcc configurations to find out headers and libraries inside its own toolchain. It will default to something like "/usr/include" and "/usr/lib".

When you are compiling with `arm-linux-gcc`, as done before by `gcc`, it will use your `arm-linux-gcc` configurations to find out headers and libraries inside its own toolchain. It can be anywhere, depending on your toolchain (i.e. "/home/eldk/usr/lib/gcc/arm-linux-gnueabi/4.2.2/..." for wallyk's).

Note that you have two different toolchains, and each one has its own files.

You cannot link a library built for "x86" into an ARM binary. They are incompatible!

`gcc` links gcc libs, `arm-linux-gcc` links arm-linux-gcc libs.

Even the headers, that only plain text, can't be the same, as different processors can have different configurations for endiannes, data sizes, etc.

**SO**

You must install your AppWeb *cross-compiled for ARM* before getting to compile your sample application.

After this, you will end up having a `appweb/appweb.h` and `-lappweb` reachable by your toolchain.

Please tell us if you need help on how to cross-compile AppWeb.
It must be a README in the sources telling how to do that.