# arm-linux-gnu-gcc fatal error: stdio.h: No such file or directory

Tags: c, linux, gcc, cross-compiling

These are the files in /usr/bin

```
[root@xilinx bin]# ls -ld arm*
-rwxr-xr-x. 1 root root  691752 Feb  5  2013 arm-linux-gnu-addr2line
-rwxr-xr-x. 1 root root  721416 Feb  5  2013 arm-linux-gnu-ar
-rwxr-xr-x. 1 root root 1297632 Feb  5  2013 arm-linux-gnu-as
-rwxr-xr-x. 1 root root  689168 Feb  5  2013 arm-linux-gnu-c++filt
-rwxr-xr-x. 1 root root  545664 Feb  6  2013 arm-linux-gnu-cpp
-rwxr-xr-x. 1 root root   34176 Feb  5  2013 arm-linux-gnu-elfedit
-rwxr-xr-x. 1 root root  544624 Feb  6  2013 arm-linux-gnu-gcc
-rwxr-xr-x. 1 root root  214400 Feb  6  2013 arm-linux-gnu-gcov
-rwxr-xr-x. 1 root root  760640 Feb  5  2013 arm-linux-gnu-gprof
-rwxr-xr-x. 2 root root 1177528 Feb  5  2013 arm-linux-gnu-ld
-rwxr-xr-x. 2 root root 1177528 Feb  5  2013 arm-linux-gnu-ld.bfd
-rwxr-xr-x. 1 root root  704672 Feb  5  2013 arm-linux-gnu-nm
-rwxr-xr-x. 1 root root  875456 Feb  5  2013 arm-linux-gnu-objcopy
-rwxr-xr-x. 1 root root 1096992 Feb  5  2013 arm-linux-gnu-objdump
-rwxr-xr-x. 1 root root  721456 Feb  5  2013 arm-linux-gnu-ranlib
-rwxr-xr-x. 1 root root  389040 Feb  5  2013 arm-linux-gnu-readelf
-rwxr-xr-x. 1 root root  693608 Feb  5  2013 arm-linux-gnu-size
-rwxr-xr-x. 1 root root  691648 Feb  5  2013 arm-linux-gnu-strings
-rwxr-xr-x. 1 root root  875456 Feb  5  2013 arm-linux-gnu-strip
```

I am following [this tutorial](http://www.aclevername.com/articles/linux-xilinx-tutorial/minimalist-initramfs.html) to cross compile a simple C program:

```
/* myinit.c
 * Build instructions:
 * ${CROSS_COMPILE}gcc -static init.c -o init
 * */

#include <stdio.h>

int
main ()
{
    printf ("\n");
    printf ("Hello world from %s!\n", __FILE__);
    while (1) { }
    return 0;
}
```

Now I save this is a .c file and try to compile it;

```
[root@xilinx Xilinx-ZC702-14.7]# arm-linux-gnu-gcc myinit.c 
myinit.c:6:19: fatal error: stdio.h: No such file or directory
compilation terminated.
```

This is hapening only when I am using arm-linux-gnu-gcc.

But when I am using gcc, it works fine.

Why is arm-linux* giving this error?

**Update**

```
[root@xilinx Xilinx-ZC702-14.7]# arm-linux-gnu-cpp -Wp,-v
ignoring nonexistent directory "/usr/lib/gcc/arm-linux-gnueabi/4.7.2/../../../../arm-linux-gnueabi/sys-include"
ignoring nonexistent directory "/usr/lib/gcc/arm-linux-gnueabi/4.7.2/../../../../arm-linux-gnueabi/include"
#include "..." search starts here:
#include <...> search starts here:
 /usr/lib/gcc/arm-linux-gnueabi/4.7.2/include
 /usr/lib/gcc/arm-linux-gnueabi/4.7.2/include-fixed
End of search list.
```

**Verbose**

```
[root@xilinx Xilinx-ZC702-14.7]# arm-linux-gnu-gcc -v myinit.c 
Using built-in specs.
COLLECT_GCC=arm-linux-gnu-gcc
COLLECT_LTO_WRAPPER=/usr/libexec/gcc/arm-linux-gnueabi/4.7.2/lto-wrapper
Target: arm-linux-gnueabi
Configured with: ../gcc-4.7.2-20121114-aarch64/configure --disable-dependency-tracking --disable-silent-rules --prefix=/usr --exec-prefix=/usr --bindir=/usr/bin --sbindir=/usr/sbin --sysconfdir=/etc --datadir=/usr/share --includedir=/usr/include --libexecdir=/usr/libexec --localstatedir=/var --sharedstatedir=/var/lib --mandir=/usr/share/man --infodir=/usr/share/info --build=x86_64-redhat-linux-gnu --host=x86_64-redhat-linux-gnu --target=arm-linux-gnueabi --enable-targets=all --program-prefix=arm-linux-gnu- --enable-languages=c --with-newlib --without-headers --disable-sjlj-exceptions --with-system-libunwind --disable-nls --disable-threads --disable-shared --disable-libmudflap --disable-libssp --disable-libgomp --disable-libquadmath --disable-gold --disable-decimal-float --enable-checking= --enable-gnu-unique-object --enable-linker-build-id --disable-plugin --enable-nls --with-system-zlib --with-bugurl=http://bugzilla.redhat.com/bugzilla/ --enable-obsolete
Thread model: single
gcc version 4.7.2 20121105 (Red Hat 4.7.2-2.aa.20121114svn) (GCC) 
COLLECT_GCC_OPTIONS='-v' '-mtls-dialect=gnu'
 /usr/libexec/gcc/arm-linux-gnueabi/4.7.2/cc1 -quiet -v myinit.c -quiet -dumpbase myinit.c -mtls-dialect=gnu -auxbase myinit -version -o /tmp/ccZNNlzj.s
GNU C (GCC) version 4.7.2 20121105 (Red Hat 4.7.2-2.aa.20121114svn) (arm-linux-gnueabi)
    compiled by GNU C version 4.4.6 20120305 (Red Hat 4.4.6-4), GMP version 4.3.1, MPFR version 2.4.1, MPC version 0.8
GGC heuristics: --param ggc-min-expand=100 --param ggc-min-heapsize=131072
ignoring nonexistent directory "/usr/lib/gcc/arm-linux-gnueabi/4.7.2/../../../../arm-linux-gnueabi/sys-include"
ignoring nonexistent directory "/usr/lib/gcc/arm-linux-gnueabi/4.7.2/../../../../arm-linux-gnueabi/include"
#include "..." search starts here:
#include <...> search starts here:
 /usr/lib/gcc/arm-linux-gnueabi/4.7.2/include
 /usr/lib/gcc/arm-linux-gnueabi/4.7.2/include-fixed
End of search list.
GNU C (GCC) version 4.7.2 20121105 (Red Hat 4.7.2-2.aa.20121114svn) (arm-linux-gnueabi)
    compiled by GNU C version 4.4.6 20120305 (Red Hat 4.4.6-4), GMP version 4.3.1, MPFR version 2.4.1, MPC version 0.8
GGC heuristics: --param ggc-min-expand=100 --param ggc-min-heapsize=131072
Compiler executable checksum: a19a7c6897fa348d9d5b59c718fa0648
myinit.c:6:19: fatal error: stdio.h: No such file or directory
compilation terminated.
```

**Host configuration**

Redhat 6, 64 bit

Comment: Looks like you need to specify a dir where `stdio.h` can be included via the `-I dir` option to the compiler.

Comment: Have you installed a standard C library for your target? You need to tell the compiler and linker where to find it.

Comment: Possible dup http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8877359/why-error-in-cross-compiling-arm-linux-gcc

Comment: What does the preprocessor for your ARM cross-compilers have as its standard include paths? (e.g. `arm-linux-gnu-cpp -Wp,-v`)

Comment: @Michael I updated above. Kindly have a look at it

Comment: Have you already tried to use some embedded Linux distro like [Buildroot](http://buildroot.uclibc.org/) or [OpenEmbedded flavor](http://www.openembedded.org/wiki/Main_Page). This distros will take care of the toolchain and package dependencies.

Comment: Buildroot appears to be a much bigger and complex than what I need

Comment: where did you unpack your toolchain?

Comment: @auselen I dont remember it. But I found all those files in /usr/bin

Comment: try to find where the stdio.h etc lays and uses gcc's sysroot to pass location.

Comment: @auselen stdio.h is in /usr/include

Comment: @gpuguy The files in `/usr/include` and `/usr/lib` are for the *host* platform, which may not be the same as the *target* platform.

Comment: I cd into /usr/include , and then tried compiling, but the same error

Comment: @JoachimPileborg you mean stdio.h for host and target (ARM) are different and placed at differnt place

Answer (score 11, accepted):

The problem here, it seems, is that you installed the compiler toolchain for the target, but didn't install a standard library for the target. You need a standard C library compiled specifically for your target platform. Either find a pre-compiled from the same place you found the compiler toolchain, or download one and cross-compile using the target toolchain.

When you have a standard C library for the target, use the flag `-I` (that's uppercase i) to tell the compiler where to find the header files, and the `-L` flag to tell the linker where to find the libraries, and e.g. `-lc` (that's the lower-case L) to tell the linker to link with the library. Something like

```
$ arm-linux-gnu-gcc -I/usr/local/target/include myinit.c -L/usr/local/target/lib -lc
```

Comment: So it's not possible to build a cross-compiler without... a cross compiler?

Answer (score 6):

This got fixed for me by installing "arm-none-eabi-newlib"

```
$ sudo yum install arm-none-eabi-newlib
```

It contained the required files in the right path.

Comment: I've done this on Fedora. However, I still get: "fatal error: stdio.h: No such file or directory"

Answer (score 1):

The most likely issue here is that the sysroot path wasn't set when this cross compiler was generated. The toolchain developers have their own reasons for doing so. You can confirm by doing

```
$ arm-linux-gnu-gcc -print-sysroot
 /not/exist
```

The toolchain developers expect us to use the standard environment variables such as ${CXX} ${CC} to cross compile. They would usually have a script provided for this purpose that among other things does the following.

```
$ export SDKTARGETSYSROOT=/path/to/sysroots/armv7at2hf-neon-fslc-linux-gnueabi

$ export CC="arm-linux-gnu-gcc -march=armv7-a -mthumb -mfpu=neon -mfloat-abi=hard --sysroot=$SDKTARGETSYSROOT"
```

So, for compiling your *.c program, in this case, myinit.c, you would do.

```
$ ${CC} myinit.c
```

Or if you like me are old school would do

```
$ arm-linux-gnu-gcc -march=armv7-a -mthumb -mfpu=neon -mfloat-abi=hard --sysroot=$SDKTARGETSYSROOT myinit.c
```